# EJS layout not working in hapi.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js, hapijs-vision

hapi.js docs explain [how to use layouts](https://hapijs.com/tutorials/views?lang=en_US#layouts), but when I set things up as described in the docs, the layout is rendered without bringing in the content. The content is rendered correctly (with no layout) when I remove the server layout config.

This app uses [`vision`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vision), which may be playing a role.

**server**

```
engines: {
    html: require('ejs')
},
relativeTo: __dirname,
path: 'templates',
layout: true,
layoutPath: 'templates/layouts',
...
```

**route**

```
handler: (request, reply) => {
    reply.view('test')
```

**templates/layouts/layout.html**

```
<html>
    <body>
        {{{content}}}
    </body>
</html>
```

**templates/test.html**

```
<h1>Test!</h1>
```

Rendered content is simply:

```
{{{content}}}
```

How can I get the content to render inside the layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the EJS syntax instead of the handlebars syntax.

**/layouts/layout.html**

```
<%- content %>
```